# Using a struct to hold information entered by the user C++

Tags: c++, struct

Okay, so I am writing a C++ program to declare a struct data type that holds the following information on an employee (First Name, Last Name, ID, Pay Rate, and Hours). My problem is that the user can only enter in the ID and First Name, then the whole program runs without letting the user enter the rest of the data.

Heres my code:

```
 #include <iostream> 
 #include <iomanip> 


    using namespace std;

    struct Employee
{

int employeeID;
char firstName;
char lastName;
float payRate;
int hours;

};



int main()
{
    int i, j;

    cout << "How Many Employees Do You Wish To Enter?:\n\n";
    cin >> j;

   Employee info;

   for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
   {
        cout << "Enter in the Data for Employee number " << i + 1 << endl;

        cout << setw(5) << "\n Please Enter The Employee ID Number: ";
        cin >> info.employeeID;

        cout << setw(5) << "\n Please Enter Employees First Name: ";
        cin >> info.firstName;

        cout << setw(5) << "\n Please Enter Employees Last Name: ";
        cin >> info.lastName;

        cout << setw(5) << "\n Please Enter Employees Pay Rate: ";
        cin >> info.payRate;

        cout << setw(5) << "\n  Please Enter The Hours The Employee Worked: 
";
        cin >> info.hours;


    }

    cout << "\n\n                                   \n";

    cout << "ID" << setw(15) << "First Name" << setw(10) << "Last Name" << 
setw(10) << "Pay Rate" << setw(10) << "Hours";
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {

    cout << "\n" << info.employeeID << setw(15) << info.firstName << setw(10) << info.lastName << setw(10) << info.payRate << setw(10) << info.hours;

}

cout << "\n\n                                    \n";



system("pause");
return 0;



};
```

Comment: What is the question? Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49432245/edit).

Comment: You need to revisit what the `char` datatype holds.

Comment: I want to display the information entered by the user under each category, like the ID information goes under "ID" and the First Names go under the "First Name", It wont let me display the data

Answer (score 0):

First, please read [Tips and tricks for using C++ I/O (input/output)](http://www.augustcouncil.com/%7Etgibson/tutorial/iotips.html). It might be helpful to understand C++ I/O.

Here are some comments on your code:

**First**

Use `string` instead of `char`.

```
struct Employee
{
    int employeeID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    float payRate;
    int hours;
};
```

**Second**

Use array of `Employee` object to store multiple employees.

```
Employee info[100];
```

**Third**

Use `cin` carefully depending data types. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
cout << "Enter in the Data for Employee number " << i + 1 << endl;
cout << setw(5) << "\n Please Enter The Employee ID Number: ";
cin >>  info[i].employeeID;
cin.ignore(); //It is placed to ignore new line character.
cout << setw(5) << "\n Please Enter Employees First Name: ";
getline (cin,  info[i].firstName);
cout << setw(5) << "\n Please Enter Employees Last Name: ";
getline (cin,  info[i].lastName);
cout << setw(5) << "\n Please Enter Employees Pay Rate: ";
cin >>  info[i].payRate;
cout << setw(5) << "\n  Please Enter The Hours The Employee Worked: ";
cin >>  info[i].hours;
```

**Fourth**

`std::getline()` can run into problems when used before `std::cin >> var`. So, `std::cin.ignore()` can be used in this case to solve the problem.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string> //Allows you to use strings, which are way more handy for text manipulation
#include <vector> //Allows you to use vector which are meant to be rezied dynamicaly, which is your case


using namespace std;

struct Employee
{

    int employeeID;
    string firstName; //HERE : use string instead of char (string are array of char)
    string lastName; //HERE : use string instead of char
    float payRate;
    int hours;

};



int main()
{
    int j; 

    cout << "How Many Employees Do You Wish To Enter?:\n\n";
    cin >> j;

    vector<struct Employee> info; //creation of the vector (dynamic array) to store the employee info the user is going to give you

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) //declare your looping iterator "i" here, you will avoid many error 
    {
        struct Employee employee_i; // create an employee at each iteration to associate the current info
        cout << "Enter in the Data for Employee number " << i + 1 << endl;

        cout << "\n Please Enter The Employee ID Number: ";
        cin >> employee_i.employeeID; 

        cout <<  "\n Please Enter Employees First Name: ";
        cin >> employee_i.firstName;

        cout << "\n Please Enter Employees Last Name: ";
        cin >> employee_i.lastName;

        cout << "\n Please Enter Employees Pay Rate: ";
        cin >> employee_i.payRate;

        cout << "\n  Please Enter The Hours The Employee Worked: ";
        cin >> employee_i.hours;

        info.push_back(employee_i); //store that employee info into your vector. Push_back() methods expands the vector size by 1 each time, to be able to put your item in it
    } // because you employee variable was create IN the loop, he will be destruct here, but not the vector which was created outside

    cout << "\n\n                                   \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) //the loop to get back all the info from the vector
    {
        cout << "ID :" << info[i].employeeID << "  First Name :" << info[i].firstName << "  Last Name :" <<
            info[i].lastName << "  Pay Rate :" << info[i].payRate << "  Hours :"<< info[i].hours;
        cout << endl;
//notice the info[i], which leads you to the employee you need and the ".hours" which leads to the hours info of that specific employee
        }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that @NanBlanc It all works but I have a couple questions , how would I be able to write it so that the "IDs" and "First Name" etc, have their own column when the program runs? For example all of the IDs entered get displayed under "ID" and then in the next column all of the First Names are displayed under "First Name" column? And my second question is How would I be able to add the employees pay together? Taking all of the Hours Worked multiplied by the Pay Rate and then add all of them together?