# Variable is getting assigned automatically

Tags: c++, for-loop

I was making a project that gets students' names, roll numbers & marks and returns percentage or grade according to need of user. I made a function using for loop to assign details(name, etc.) to variable but during change of for loop's argument, program was assigning ""(null) to the first variable in execution part. Am I missing any code here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Data 
{
    public: 
    int Rno[3], phy[3], mat[3], chem[3];
    char name[3][100];

    void getInfo()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter your name: ";
            gets(name[i]);

            cout << "Enter your Roll number: ";
            cin >> Rno[i];

            cout << "Enter your Physics marks: ";
            cin >> phy[i];

            cout << "Enter your Maths marks: ";
            cin >> mat[i];

            cout << "Enter your Chemistry marks: ";
            cin >> chem[i];
       }
    };
};

int main()
{
    Data d;

    d.getInfo();
    puts(d.name[1]);
}
```

Comment: Use `std::array` and `std::string`. Don't use `gets/puts`.

Comment: [using-a-struct-to-hold-information-entered-by-the-user-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432245/using-a-struct-to-hold-information-entered-by-the-user-c/49433104#49433104). Look at answers. Might give you idea how to do it.

Comment: `""(null)` - no, that's definitely not the same. `""`  is a C string literal, and as such it contains a terminating `\0`. It's the empty string, so it contains _only_ that `\0` character. But since it's a valid string, it is different from `NULL`. As pointed out in the first comment, use `std::string`. It's much easier to work with.

Comment: @SombreroChicken, can you please add it as answer? It is working and I want to add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First an explanation.   Then some options to address the problem.

The problem is that you are mixing line-oriented input (`gets()`) with formatted input (`cin >> ....`) on the same input device/stream.

Such functions treat whitespace—particularly newlines—differently.    And, because of that, you can get unexpected interactions.  In this case, `cin >> chem[i]` will read an integral value, stop when it encounters a newline, leave the newline character waiting to be read.   Then `gets()`—in the next iteration of the loop—will encounter the newline, and return immediately (hence the "null", to use your description).

OK;  that's the explanation.   What to do about it?

The solution is not to mix such styles of input.   One option is to consistently use line oriented input to read *everything* as a string, and then separately parse the string.

Some people will suggest approaches that involve discarding (or "flushing") the offending newlines.   That approach doesn't work well if your input is complex (e.g., lots of different statements reading from the same stream in different ways) because it is necessary to ensure *every* stray newline is discarded.   It is also error-prone—you can unintentionally discard input your program needs to read.

Also avoid using `gets()` like the plague.   It has been removed from recent C standards for a reason—it is inherently unsafe.

There are various ways using C++ streams (like `cin`) to safely read strings and other types.   For example, if `some_str` is of type `std::string`, then `std::getline(std::cin, some_str)` can be used to read a complete line of input.  `std::getline()` also has the advantage that it can read a string of arbitrary size.    But, still, avoid using `std::getline(cin, some_str)` and streaming input (`cin >> ...`) on the same stream—because they *still* handle newlines differently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with not flushing `cout`. In your case, inside the loop, `cout` must be flushed before calling `gets`.

```
cout << "Enter your name: " << endl;  // This cout should be flushed properly **with** new line character
gets(name[i]);
```

From [ProXicT's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347934/variable-is-getting-assigned-automatically/50352259#comment87714090_50349144):

```
cout << "Enter your name: " << flush;  // This cout should be flushed properly **without** new line character
    gets(name[i]);
```

Comment: You didn't explain why in your example the `std::cout` is flushed properly. It's because of the `std::endl` sideeffect which flushes the buffer after the line feed. If, however, OP didn't want to put line feed at the end, he could use `std::flush` instead of `std::endl`.